# code after Gwt rpc AsyncCallbak will not be executed?

Tags: gwt, rpc

I can't understand why the code after the gwt rpc AsyncCallback will not be executed?

for example I have the interface AppService extends RemoteService, So I'll have AsyncAppService which does the async call.

the following code

```
            AppServiceAsync service = GWT.create (AppService.class);
        service.getCurrentUser(new AsyncCallback<Employee>(){

            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

            }

            public void onSuccess(Employee result) {
                currentUser = result;
            }

        });
 // if i have the code after the above call, these code will not be execute, what is the problem
//code following will not be executed if they are in the same function.
    boolean isAdmin = false;
        if(currentUser!=null){
            if(currentUser.getUserRole().equals("ROLE_ADMIN") ||
                    currentUser.getUserRole().equals("ROLE_MANAGER")){
                isAdmin = true;
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your explaination

Answer (score 5):

You should understand the nature of the Async call. The programm execution will not be waiting when you call `service.getCurrentUser`. The programm will continue to the next line (`boolean isAdmin = false`) and **it will be true for some time** that `(currentUser == null)` until method `getCurrentUser` is executing. You should move not executed block of code into the `onSuccess` handler

This example should look something like this:

```
service.getCurrentUser(new AsyncCallback<Employee>(){

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

    }

    public void onSuccess(Employee result) {
        currentUser = result;
        if (currentUser != null) {
            if (currentUser.getUserRole().equals("ROLE_ADMIN") ||
                currentUser.getUserRole().equals("ROLE_MANAGER")) {
                isAdmin = true;
            }
        }

    }

});
```

I assume that currentUser and isAdmin are class fields, but not local variables. If `isAdmin` is local than you can wrap this variable into the final array: `final boolean[] isAdmin = new boolean[1]` and call it like `isAdmin[0]`

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I didn't realised the synchronisation problem. But here is a new problem, if the function is asychro, in any way that the code followed the function will be executed, so the result of the function will not be waited? And What do you mean for wrap the variable into the final array? currentUser is a class but isAdmin is boolean.

Comment: You are right, if the function is async then the result will not be waited for.
Java does not support closures. So inside the anonymous class you can't use not final local variables. It will not be compiled.

Comment: Do you mean that, because the property of currentUser what I've used is not a final local variable, so the code after the asynchro func concerning the class will not be compiled so as to protect the asyncro mecanisme?

Comment: No, I didn't mean this. Please read this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science), "Inner classes (Java)" section. And here is nice explanation about async calls http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideGettingUsedToAsyncCalls It should not be very difficult to understand it, but anyway you can ask questions about this 2 articles.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you are a broker in a non-computerised stock/commodities market of the old days. Let's imagine that it functions in the following manner.

It's Monday 9.30 am. You have these planned in sequence. In fact, you are so experienced it is programmed into you:

Programme BuyAlBanySteel(500):

1. You want to make a call to buy 500 AlbanySteel.
2. Pass the call board which will be circulated around the trading floor.
3. When call board returns with the offer and offer is agreeable to you,
   approach offeror to buy the stock.

Programme Drink Coffee

1. Pour Coffee
2. Drink coffee.

Caveat you have to deal with: getting a call response takes at least 10 minutes, or even an hour. It is asynchronous. You have an idea how long it takes but it is not certain.

So this is your plan in sequence for the morning:

1. execute BuyAlBanySteel(500)
2. Drink coffee.

Let me ask you, how would you structure your work flow? Would you structure it this way? Let's say each task takes you blocks of one minute to perform.

```
9.31 am
Send offer(
  buy = 500 AlbanySteel
  messenger = annie
  When annie comes back, analyse offer.
  Pour Annie a cup of tea.
)

9.32 am
if (annie has an agreeable offer) buy 500 AlbanySteel.

9.33 am
Pour Coffee.

9.34
Drink Coffee.
```

Of course you can't. The reason is the following line

```
9.32 am
if (annie has an agreeable offer) buy 500 AlbanySteel.
```

will not be performed properly. It will appear not to to have been performed because Annie would not have come back with an offer yet. It might take her another 10 minutes or an hour to come back with an offer.

So, this is how you have to execute your work flow

```
9.31 am
Send offer(
  buy = 500 AlbanySteel
  messenger = annie
  when annie comes back,
  analyse offer.
  Pour Annie a cup of tea.
  if (annie has an agreeable offer) buy 500 AlbanySteel.
)

9.33 am
Pour Coffee.

9.34
Drink Coffee.
```

So, in GWT pseudocode, which one would you choose to execute?

Would you execute this:

```
BuyAlbanySteelAsync albanyService = GWT.create(BuyAlbanySteel.class);

albanyService.getOffer(
  new Task<Annie>(){
    onFailure(Annie){Do nothing}

    OnSuccess(Annie){
       analyse offer.
       Pour Annie a cup of tea.
    }
  }
);

if(Annie has agreeable offer)
  buy the stock.
```

Or this:

```
BuyAlbanySteelAsync albanyService = GWT.create(BuyAlbanySteel.class);

albanyService.getOffer(
  new Task<Annie>(){
    onFailure(Annie){Do nothing}

    OnSuccess(Annie){
       analyse offer.
       Pour Annie a cup of tea.
       if(Annie has agreeable offer)
         buy the stock.
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: What you said are right, It helped me understand the synchronisation problem. But here is a new problem, if the function is asychro, in any way that the code followed the function will be executed, so the result of the function will not be waited?

Comment: Trying to do synchronous calls is a bad idea. You need to realign your programming style to adapt to async programming, for effective and efficient web-apps. I do't have a clear idea what's behind the javascript engine on the browser, but attempting synchronous calls will cause the performance of your app/page to be patchy.

Comment: Usage of synchronous calls will slow (or sometimes block) your application interface reaction on user actions significantly because user will be waiting for server response each time RPC is called.